# how to make text classification by lstm

Tags: python, lstm

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    encoder,
    tf.keras.layers.Embedding(len(encoder.get_vocabulary()), 64, mask_zero=True),
    tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(64,  return_sequences=True)),
    tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(32)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)
```

How to modify this code?

Comment: `tokenizer` is not needed in the second line of your code. It should be removed. First layer of your model should be embedding layer

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (_i.e._ regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed, and thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work](/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question)?

Answer (score 1):

Replace `tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(64)),` with `tf.keras.layers.LSTM(64),`.

Answer (score 0):

In case you re using **tensorflow-gpu** with Cudnn use

```
tf.keras.layers.CuDNNLSTM
```

It will improve the training